# How can I increment/decrement separate counters in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I made a ticket order system for a project, however when I want to increment the amount of one of the tickets both of the counters increase. I am not sure why this happens, but I assume it is because only one value is stored in state.

```
export default function Ticket() {

    const [count, setState] = useState(0); // useState returns a pair. 'count' is the current state. 'setCount' is a function we can use to update the state.

    function increment(e) {
        //setCount(prevCount => prevCount+=1);
        setState(function (prevCount) {
            return (prevCount += 1);
        });
    }

    function decrement() {
        setState(function (prevCount) {
            if (prevCount > 0) {
                return (prevCount -= 1);
            } else {
                return (prevCount = 0);
            }
        });
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <section className="ticket-step">
                <h1>TICKETS</h1>
            </section>

            <div className="ticket-booking is-flexbox">

                <section className="ticket-content">

                    <ul className="tickets-tab is-flexbox">
                        <li>Tickets</li>
                        <li>Abbonementen</li>
                    </ul>


                    <div className="ticket-list-section">

                        <div className="ticket-list-details heading">
                            <div id="calender">
                                <h3>Datum : 30 - 10 - 2022</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div id="opening">
                                <h3>Openingstijden: 12:00 - 20:00 </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="ticket-list-details">

                            <div className="ticket-block">

                                <div className="ticket-title">
                                    <h3>Parkeer ticket</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="price">
                                    <h3>Prijs: $20</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="counter">
                                    <button className="increase-amount" onClick={increment}>+</button>
                                    <input type="text" className="amount" defaultValue="0" value={count}/>
                                    <button className="decrease-amount" onClick={decrement}>-</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div className="ticket-block">

                                <div className="ticket-title">
                                    <h3>Early Horror-ticket</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="price">
                                    <h3>Prijs : $59</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="counter">
                                    <button className="increase-amount" onClick={increment}>+</button>
                                    <input type="text" className="amount" defaultValue="0" value={count}/>
                                    <button className="decrease-amount" onClick={decrement}>-</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <aside className="sidebar-overview">
                    <h1>besteloverzicht</h1>
                    <div className="sidebar-overview-content">

                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <div className="sidebar-overview-total">
                        <h3>Totaal: $0</h3>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried to change `useState` and somehow store different states of the counters in an array, but that didn't work.

How can use the counters separately and store the state of the different buttons?

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002) using your code.

Comment: _"I tried to change useState and somehow store different states of the counters in an array, but that didn't work._" This is definitely an approach you can take. What didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say create a Button component and use that instead of adding more counters... as you might want to re-use this in different pages later as well.

Button.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Button() {
  const [count, setState] = useState(0); // useState returns a pair. 'count' is the current state. 'setCount' is a function we can use to update the state.

  function increment(e) {
    //setCount(prevCount => prevCount+=1);
    setState(function (prevCount) {
      return (prevCount += 1);
    });
  }

  function decrement() {
    setState(function (prevCount) {
      if (prevCount > 0) {
        return (prevCount -= 1);
      } else {
        return (prevCount = 0);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <button className="increase-amount" onClick={increment}>
        +
      </button>
      <input type="text" className="amount" defaultValue="0" value={count} />
      <button className="decrease-amount" onClick={decrement}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

and just re-use it in your page;

```
export default function Ticket() {
    return (
        <div>
            <section className="ticket-step">
                <h1>TICKETS</h1>
            </section>

            <div className="ticket-booking is-flexbox">

                <section className="ticket-content">

                    <ul className="tickets-tab is-flexbox">
                        <li>Tickets</li>
                        <li>Abbonementen</li>
                    </ul>


                    <div className="ticket-list-section">

                        <div className="ticket-list-details heading">
                            <div id="calender">
                                <h3>Datum : 30 - 10 - 2022</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div id="opening">
                                <h3>Openingstijden: 12:00 - 20:00 </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="ticket-list-details">

                            <div className="ticket-block">

                                <div className="ticket-title">
                                    <h3>Parkeer ticket</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="price">
                                    <h3>Prijs: $20</h3>
                                </div>

                                <Button/>

                            </div>

                            <div className="ticket-block">

                                <div className="ticket-title">
                                    <h3>Early Horror-ticket</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div className="price">
                                    <h3>Prijs : $59</h3>
                                </div>

                                <Button/>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <aside className="sidebar-overview">
                    <h1>besteloverzicht</h1>
                    <div className="sidebar-overview-content">

                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <div className="sidebar-overview-total">
                        <h3>Totaal: $0</h3>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps, see how I changed the value for the input tags and useState
Let me know if it worked

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setState] = useState({
    first: 0,
    second: 0
  });

  function increment(type) {
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [type]: count[type] + 1
    }))
  }

  function decrement(type) {
    if(count[type] === 0) return;
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [type]: count[type] - 1
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="ticket-step">
        <h1>TICKETS</h1>
      </section>

      <div className="ticket-booking is-flexbox">
        <section className="ticket-content">
          <ul className="tickets-tab is-flexbox">
            <li>Tickets</li>
            <li>Abbonementen</li>
          </ul>

          <div className="ticket-list-section">
            <div className="ticket-list-details heading">
              <div id="calender">
                <h3>Datum : 30 - 10 - 2022</h3>
              </div>

              <div id="opening">
                <h3>Openingstijden: 12:00 - 20:00 </h3>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="ticket-list-details">
              <div className="ticket-block">
                <div className="ticket-title">
                  <h3>Parkeer ticket</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="price">
                  <h3>Prijs: $20</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="counter">
                  <button className="increase-amount" onClick={() => increment("first")}>
                    +
                  </button>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="amount"
                    defaultValue="0"
                    value={count.first}
                  />
                  <button className="decrease-amount" onClick={() => decrement("first")}>
                    -
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="ticket-block">
                <div className="ticket-title">
                  <h3>Early Horror-ticket</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="price">
                  <h3>Prijs : $59</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="counter">
                  <button className="increase-amount" onClick={() => increment("second")}>
                    +
                  </button>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="amount"
                    defaultValue="0"
                    value={count.second}
                  />
                  <button className="decrease-amount" onClick={() => decrement("second")}>
                    -
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <aside className="sidebar-overview">
          <h1>besteloverzicht</h1>
          <div className="sidebar-overview-content"></div>
          <hr />
          <div className="sidebar-overview-total">
            <h3>Totaal: $0</h3>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a counter hook as well as a counter component.

useCounter.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";

// An enum to track whether it's increment or decrement

const actionEnum = {
  INCREMENT: "increment",
  DECREMENT: "decerement"
};
const useCounter = (initialValue = 0) => {

  // State to hold the value
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialValue);

  // The function that set's the count based on the name of the element

  function handleChange({ target }) {
    const { name } = target;
    setCount((prev) => (name === actionEnum.INCREMENT ? prev + 1 : prev - 1));
  }
  return {
    count,
    handleChange,
    actionEnum
  };
};

export default useCounter;
```

Counter.jsx

```
import useCounter from "./useCounter";

const Counter = () => {
  const { count, handleChange, actionEnum } = useCounter();

  return (
    <>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button name={actionEnum.INCREMENT} onClick={handleChange}>
        +
      </button>
      <button name={actionEnum.DECREMENT} onClick={handleChange}>
        -
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default Counter;
```

Then finally just import the Counter component for each counter you need.

Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-hooks-0ohyun?file=/src/App.js

You can also update the component so that it takes a prop for a fn that sets a global state which tracks all the counters

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 counters instead of just one, so you'll have 2 useState() statements.

```
const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);
const [count2, setCount2] = useState(0);
```

Then your buttons and displays need to reference the separate counter states appropriately.

```
    <div className="counter">
      <button className="increase-amount" onClick={increment}>+</button>
      <input type="text" className="amount" defaultValue="0" value={count1}/>
      <button className="decrease-amount" onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </div>
```

You'll also need to have 2 separate increment functions and 2 separate decrement functions. Alternately, you can have one increment function that takes an argument to specify which counter to update.

Answer (score 0):

## How to Increment/Decrement Separate Counters in React or RN using useState Hooks? (Modern Solution)

**1 -  Create A Reusable Component where your Counter lives**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import styles from "./style";
import MinusIcon from "../../assets/svg/minus-icon.svg";
import MinusIconActive from "../../assets/svg/minus-icon-active.svg";
import PlusIconActive from "../../assets/svg/plus-icon-active.svg";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.counterContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            if (count > 1) {
              setCount(count - 1);
            }
          }}
          style={styles.counterButton}
        >
          {count < 2 ? <MinusIcon /> : <MinusIconActive />}
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View>
          <Text style={styles.countNumber}>{count}</Text>
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setCount(count + 1);
          }}
          style={styles.counterButton}
        >
          <PlusIconActive />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

**2 -  Import your Reusable Counter Component to your Page or Screen (and you can also pass props and parameters to it)**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import Counter from "./Counter"

function Cart() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Counter /> 
      <Counter />
      <Counter />   
    </View>
  );
}

export default Cart;
```

Hopefully, this helps you implement a different solution from the suggestions above

*... that's all folks*  .